# Validação Flask WTForms

Tags: python, validação, flask

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto web e estou tendo problemas na parte de validação de formulário.

Segue as minhas validações:

```
# REGRAS DE VALIDAÇÃO #

def validate_username(form, username):
    if dao.buscar_por_id(username.data):
        raise ValidationError('Esse username já existe')


def validate_email(form, email):
    if dao.busca_por_email(email.data):
        raise ValidationError('Esse email já foi cadastrado')


class ValidaFormulario(Form):
    username = StringField('username', [
        validators.Length(min=4, max=25,
                          message='Username deve ter entre 4 e 25 caracteress'),
        validators.DataRequired(), validate_username
    ])
    email = StringField('email', [validators.DataRequired(), validate_email])
    senha = PasswordField('senha', [
        validators.Length(min=8, max=32,
                          message='Senha deve ter entre 8 e 32 caracteres'),
        validators.EqualTo('confirma', message='Senha confirmada incorretamente'),
        validators.DataRequired()
    ])
    confirma = PasswordField('confirma', [validators.DataRequired()])
```

Meu arquivo html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}

<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Cadastro</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
    <link rel="icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='morgan_icon.png') }}">
</head>
<body>
    <form class="box" action="{{ url_for('criar') }}" method="post">
        <h1>Cadastro</h1>
        <br>
        <div class="social.media">
            <ul class="list-social-media">
                <a href="https://pt-br.facebook.com/login/"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                <a href="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin/signinchooser?service=accountsettings&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmyaccount.google.com%3Futm_source%3Daccount-marketing-page%26utm_medium%3Dgo-to-account-button&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/?hl=pt-br"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
             </ul>
        </div>
        <br>
        <p class="description-primary">Coloque seus dados pessoais</p>

        {{ render_field(form.username, 'Username', autofocus=true) }}
        {{ render_field(form.email, 'Email', type='email') }}
        {{ render_field(form.senha, 'Senha') }}
        {{ render_field(form.confirma, 'Confirmar Senha') }}

        <!--
        <input class="inputField" required type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
        <input class="inputField" required type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
        <input class="inputField" required type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha">
        <input class="inputField" required type="password" name="confirma" placeholder="Confirmar senha">
        -->

        <input type="submit" value="Criar conta">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Se eu colocar os dados corretamente, eles são cadastrados, mas quando erro alguma coisa, recebo esse erro:

```
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
```

Comment: Os WTFoms podem grar uma view automaticamente, baseada num model. Mas você tem que configurar isso: colocar o código do model, e os trechos em que você associa o model aos WTF para poderem funcioanar esses validadores é importante para ficar mais fácil responder essa questão. Sem isso, algum usuário muito especializado dos WTF até pode saber a resposta, mas são bem menos pessoas que todo mundo que entende de Python no site, que podem ajudar no caso de um exemplo mais completo.

Comment: O ideal seria consegir criar um "exemplo mínimo reprodutível": um HTML de pouquíssmas linahas e todo o setup do seu projeto em aquivos mínimos para reproduzir o erro. Isso é: se algueḿ pudesse vir aqui, copiar 3 ou 4 arquvivos de exemplo mínimo para a maquina local, e com isso conseguir instalar e executar o projeto. Eu entendo que isso pode ser complicado - mas mais alguma informação sobre o seu projeto é necessária de qualquer forma.